# C# - Access controls in a dynamic Windows Form from backgroundworker

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a Windows Form application that makes system changes when the user clicks a button and I would like a dynamic Form to popup with a ProgressBar to indicate to the user that something is happening.

A background worker should be perfect for this, but I don't know how to access the controls from a dynamically created Form.

Code so far:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> createUserMasterSettings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        createUserMasterSettings.Add("key1", "data1");
        createUserMasterSettings.Add("key2", "data2");
        createUserMasterSettings.Add("key3", "data3");
        createUserMasterSettings.Add("key4", "data4");
        createUserMasterSettings.Add("key5", "data5");

        Form reportProgressForm = new Form();
        reportProgressForm.Text = "Progress";
        reportProgressForm.Size = new Size(400, 300);

        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        progressBar.Size = new Size(180, 20);
        progressBar.Location = new Point(10, 200);
        progressBar.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar.Maximum = createUserMasterSettings.Count;
        progressBar.Step = 1;
        progressBar.Visible = true;

        Button newUserReportProgressButton = new Button();
        newUserReportProgressButton.Text = "OK";
        newUserReportProgressButton.Size = new Size(20, 10);
        newUserReportProgressButton.Location = new Point(10, 230);
        newUserReportProgressButton.Click += (_, args) => { reportProgressForm.Visible = false; reportProgressForm.Dispose(); };
        newUserReportProgressButton.Visible = true;
        newUserReportProgressButton.Enabled = false;

        reportProgressForm.Controls.Add(progressBar);
        reportProgressForm.Controls.Add(newUserReportProgressButton);
        reportProgressForm.Show();

        createNewUserBGW.RunWorkerAsync(createUserMasterSettings);
    }
    void createNewUserBGW_DoWork(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> createUserMasterSettings = (Dictionary<string, string>)e.Argument;
        for (int j = 0; j < createUserMasterSettings.Count; j++)
        {
            createNewUserBGW.ReportProgress(j);
        }

    }
    void createNewUserBGW_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Update the Progress Bar on the dynamically created Form on UI thread
    }
```

I will have more controls on the dynamic form but I've omitted them for brevity.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You're already passing in a whole bunch of *other* values into the BGW, so you know how to provide arbitrary values for a BGW.  A progress bar is no different than any other data you want to send.

Comment: You would just need to do what the designer automatically does for you: declare a field in the class that stores a reference to the control.  Right now everything is a local variable, so you can't get to them from another method.  Using a lambda to implement the event handler is the other way, you already know how to do that since you used it for the Click event.  There is no particular advantage to avoid creating the BGW locally as well.